# Extract data from SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, strongly-typed-dataset

I've connected to database, using data set .xsr now I wan't to extract all rows in my table. Here is my table structure :

```
Lastname
Address
zipcode
city
country
email
```

So here is one example of table row entry :

Danish Morten Olsen 58b 82341 Kobenhavn Denmark email@email.com

Now I'd like for someone to tell me how can I extract this info for all entries in the table in format :

```
<tr>
   <td>Lastname</td>
   <td>Address</td>
   <td>zipcode</td>
   <td>city</td>
   <td>country</td>
   <td>email</td>
</tr>
```

where of course one html table row represents one table row in database, I'm a newbie just two days ago installed necessary tools, database and started programming asp <% %>(asp noob yes, programming noob no) .. this is important so please answer if you can spare time .

thank you

Comment: Asp Classic or ASP.NET, if classic and why not start with ASP.NET?

Comment: @comrade: you need to highlight your code section and then click on the "code" button (010 101) in the toolbar to properly format it - including XML and HTML markup - see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard ASP.NET Webforms (which is what I guess you'll be using) doesn't give you total control over your HTML - you're not programming directly in HTML and markup, but against an abstracted "webform" model. E.g. you use and create server-side objects like data source (to grab your data), a gridview etc. - and the server control then really renders out the HTML to be sent back to the customer's browser.

So you might have a SQL data source to reach into your SQL Server table and grab the data:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString2 %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Lastname], [Address], [zipcode], [city], 
                          [country], [email] FROM [Addresses]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and then hook that up to a data-bound ListView on your ASP.NET form:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">Lastname:
    <asp:Label ID="LastnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Lastname") %>' />
    <br />
    Address: <asp:Label ID="AddressLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Address") %>' /><br />
    zipcode: <asp:Label ID="zipcodeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zipcode") %>' /><br />
    city: <asp:Label ID="cityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("city") %>' /><br />
    country: <asp:Label ID="countryLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("country") %>' /><br />
    email: <asp:Label ID="emailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' />
    <br /><br /></span>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <span>No data was returned.</span>
  </EmptyDataTemplate>
  <LayoutTemplate>
     <div ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
          style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <span ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
     </div>
     <div style="text-align: center;background-color: #5D7B9D;
                 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;">
     </div>
   </LayoutTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Check out the official [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/learn/) which has plenty of articles, tutorials, screen casts and demos on how to get started on ASP.NET webform development.

If you want total control over your markup, you should check out [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) which is a new concept for ASP.NET developers, but which might be a lot more along the lines of what you already know from PHP programming. Here, you do have total control over your HTML and every bit and byte being sent back to the browser.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://www.learnasp.com/freebook/asp/dbsimple.aspx

If you've just started learning ASP, you should rather start having a look at ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Your post led me to believe you were coding in Classic ASP, as opposed to ASP.NET. I recommend that you get started by watching some of the videos over on [asp.net/learn](http://www.asp.net/learn). Start with this one on [how to get data out of the database](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-videos/video-392.aspx) using a DataSet and Gridview by creating a data access layer (DAL) in your app. Optionally, you could read the [HTML version of the tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-01-vb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I never use asp but I did same thing in JSP, I just came across the link

http://www.powerasp.com/content/database/using_select.asp

This would probably help your using asp.